# How get the column title of the first empty column in openpyxl worksheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

for columns in dr_ws.iter_cols(max_row =1, min_col=8)   :
print(columns)

[Here are the values associated with Columns in just Row 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQVlA.jpg)
[The actual cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7N81.jpg)

so 005 is in H1
116 is in V1.
then the next empty Cell is W1 which has no value.

I need a code that will return just the Column title 'W'. I am not sure how to go on. Need help finding the column title of the first empty column

output should be something like : Column = W

what should I change/add to my code

Comment: Please include all details in your post, not as links.

Answer (score 0):

There are two utilities in openpyxl that you will need for this. First, use the `worksheet.max_column`, which will give you the last column which has data in it. This will be a number. So, use the `get_column_letter()` to convert the number to letter.

Note: max_column() will return the last column for all rows where data is present. So, if you have data till Z in row 2, the returned value will be 26. OR, if you have blanks in W-Z, but have data in row 1 in AA1, this will return 27. So, be sure that you are using this correctly. Let me know if those additional conditions hold true in your case.

A sample code is given below...

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('yourfile.xlsx')
dr_ws=wb['Sheet1']
print(get_column_letter(dr_ws.max_column))
### This will return "W"
```

Comment: You don't need `get_column_letter()` as cells have the `column_letter`property.

Comment: Hi @CharlieClark, Thanks. Are you suggesting to use `dr_ws.cell(1,dr_ws.max_column).column_letter`? Is that faster? I used `get_column_letter()` as `max_column` returns a number. Was trying to avoid iterating through a loop

Comment: That's not the way to think about it. `ws.max_column` is virtual and has to be calculated from all the cells but really isn't of great significance. The question is poor and unclear but, suggests that the first empty cell of a particular row is required. This may differ from `ws.max_column`. But the question is unclear and should either be improved or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```py
# iter_cols yields a tuple of cells, though in this case 
# it will only contain 1 cell because max_row=1
for cells in dr_ws.iter_cols(max_row=1, min_col=8):
    for cell in cells:
        # An empty cell has a value of None
        if cell.value is None:
            print(cell.column_letter)
```

Be sure to read openpyxl's documentation, in particular:

- https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html

---

As a function:

```py
def get_first_empty_column_letter(max_row=1, min_col=8):
    # iter_cols yields a tuple of cells
    for cells in dr_ws.iter_cols(max_row=max_row, min_col=min_col):
        for cell in cells:
            # An empty cell has a value of None
            if cell.value is None:
                # The function returns immediately upon finding the first empty cell
                return cell.column_letter
```

Comment: okay this is good so far, but it returns all the empty columns. I just need the next column. So instead of returning all of the columns, how would i just returned the first empty column.                       list_ = []
    for cells in dr_ws.iter_cols(max_row=1, min_col=8):
        for cell in cells:
        # An empty cell has a value of None
            if cell.value is None:
                list_.append(cell.column_letter)
                print(list_[0])

Comment: I figured it out, thank you so much!!

Comment: No problemo. I've updated my answer to show how I would do it.